# Live TeXing while taking notes

Tags: editors

How do you go about taking notes in class? I have a moderate typing speed of about 60 wpm, but I find myself unable to keep up with my class many times getting distracted by the formatting a lot. Is there any editor that quickly allows one to do this? I find it a hassle to type

```
\begin{equation}
\end{equation}
```

every time, so is there any way to quicken this process. I know there are some editors that allow you to do this, but I don't know which ones in particular.
Thanks.

EDIT: If it is important, I run the latest version of OS X on an old Mac. Not sure if that is important, but just in-case there are software issues.

Comment: LaTeX isn't  suited for the job. Use a pen and some paper. Convert it to nice typeset notes as homework.

Comment: Yes, most of the time I do stick with the traditional pen and paper, but sometimes I decide to Live-TeX it. I have heard of some people who do this on a regular basis which is what primarily got me interested.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have done it several times. But you have to know your editor and shortcuts. In my experience your speed will highly depend on how efficient you can use templates (e.g. itemize environment with first item etc.).

Comment: I support @TeXnician ; it is possible, I've also done this several times, especially in undergrad math classes. As said, know your editor, its shortcuts, and maybe have some templates for environments etc.
Furthermore, I suggest to just get the text/formulae/what ever is presented in the lecture without spending time for formatting. Just have the logical structure fixed, and do everything else after class. I've always had pen and paper next to my computer; you'll need it as soon as the lecturer draws a figure on the black board :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Typora](http://typora.io) as mentioned by Erwan Grelier is an excellent choice, and would probably my first choice.

There is also [Caret](https://caret.io), live previews of math feels a little buggy / can take a while to show sometimes (i.e. Typora feels a little better on that front), but it has a really nice `Go To Heading...` feature where you can instantly fuzzy search the whole document for any level markdown heading, so navigation is super quick. I sometimes use Caret to search/navigate existing notes for this feature alone.

When that is all said, I would definitely also recommend to use pen and paper in-class and type it up afterwards. Handwriting seems to help both learning and memorization, and seeing the material multiple times, i.e. giving it at least a second pass, is a good idea anyway. Nothing beats handwriting for in-class notes IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I realize now that pen and paper-in class is much better, that way you are actually focused on the material rather than 'transcribing'. I agree with Johannes_B's answer to just 'TeX' them later if nessecary...

Comment: Yes, most of the courses I did the best in, I also had time to type of a nice set of condensed notes in LaTeX (which today would be Typora).

Answer (score 0):

I know [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org) has a lot of keyboards shortcuts both embedded and customizable (ctrl + shift + N for a new equation environment), but personally for typing notes in class I use [Typora](https://typora.io), a Markdown software enabling the quick formating of documents including LaTeX, with live preview, it also could suits your needs.